# To insert multiple check box values into separate rows in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, resultset

I need help in inserting the multiple check box values into separate rows in mysql database.

**Work flow:**

1.The user selects the product check box and enters a description about the product in the text box next to the particular check box.

2.After selecting the check boxes the user hits the save button.

3.On clicking save ,the product details should be inserted into the database.
  Note: User can select multiple check box values.

**Issue:**

I have used the general method to insert values,but only one check box value is getting inserted into the database.I need to insert multiple check box values along with its text box values into the database as separate rows once I click on the save button.

This is my code

**products.jsp**

```
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="web.Products"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <form method="post" action="Save_Products">   
<b>          
            Brand Name:<font color="green">
            <% String brand_name=(String)session.getAttribute("brand_name");
       out.print(brand_name);%> 
        <c:set var="brand_name" value="brand_name" scope="session"  />
       </font></b>         
            <table>            
                <tr>                
                    <th> Products</th> 
                    <th> Description </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
               <td> <b><%
      List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("list");
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
           out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" value=\""  + prod.getProductname() + "\">"  + prod.getProductname()+"<br>");
            } %> </b></td>   

            <td><%for(Products prod: pdts){
            out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" style=\"width:50px; height:22px\"/><br/>"); 
        } 

      }  
            %> </td>  

        </tr>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <tr><td align="center">  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/> </td></tr> 
            </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Servlet code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class Save_Products extends HttpServlet {
 static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pdt";
     static final String dbUser = "root";
     static final String dbPass = "root";
    @Override
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            ResultSet rs=null;
            Connection connection = null;  
            try{
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String brand_name =(String) session.getAttribute("brand_name");
    String prod=request.getParameter("prod");
    String desc=request.getParameter("desc");


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection (dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);

String sql="insert into pdt_list(brand_name,product_name,desc)values(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 

 prep.setString(1, brand_name);
 prep.setString(2, prod);
 prep.setString(3,desc);

int i=prep.executeUpdate();

if(i>0)
{    
   out.print("Product Details Saved Successfully...");
 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Save_Success.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);    
}
else{
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Save_Failure.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);   
}

prep.close();
       }
     catch(Exception E){
//Any Exceptions will be caught here
System.out.println("The error is"+E.getMessage());

    }  

        finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("The error is"+ex.getMessage());
            }
                }

}

}
```

Comment: It seems that your request sends parameters arrays, if that is the case, you should use `request.getParameterValues(...);` instead of `request.getParameter(...)` and then, loop through this arrays to insert more then one row in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your servlet use `request.getParameterValues("prod")` to get the array of all the inputs you received. `request.getParameter("prod")` will just return you one. Same goes for your `desc` values.

Then loop through the values and insert them all into your DB

```
String [] prod_list = request.getParameterValues("prod");
String [] desc_list = request.getParameterValues("desc");
// set up your query

PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

// just a precaution here getting min so we do not get outofbounds exception on one of the arrays
// both arrays should be of same size - if not, something is wrong on your jsp logic
int num_values = Math.min(prod_list.size(), desc_list.size());

int count_updated = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < num_values; i++){
    prep.setString(1, brand_name);
    prep.setString(2, prod_list[i]);
    prep.setString(3,desc_list[i]);
    count_updated += prep.executeUpdate();
}

// Rest of your logic
```

This is a simpler way of using `PreparedStatement`. Check how to do batch inserts with `PreparedStatement`. [This](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/) should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I got the concept.Can you please guide me in looping the values ?

Comment: I just updated my answer with some code to get you started